# Gender capture the User with omniauth - facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I'm with a doubt here. I am using the gem ' omniauth - facebook ' and could bring up on the screen the name of the User , photo and email. I would like to get new data as gender for example. Dai created a migration add the field to the users table , put the method in view , all right. However I can not figure out how to write the method name and is giving indisponivel method . Does anyone have any ideas? I know that the error is in the method name but not know how to call it. Thanks. 
[Error Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMvt3.png)

[Erb Code Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQX6o.png)

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create
    do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.public_profile.gender = auth.public_profile.gender
      user.token = auth.credentials.token
      user.expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Code of User.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.email = auth.info.email 
      user.public_profile.gender = auth.public_profile.gender     
      user.token = auth.credentials.token
      user.expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end

  

end

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've created your model based on a tutorial and that tutorial is out of date for facebooks current API, which you can see here

[Facebook Auth Hash, complete](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash)

So in this, you're looking for gender in under info, but it's under extra->raw_info - meaning your code would look more like:

```
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.name = auth.info.name
  user.image = auth.info.image
  user.email = auth.info.email
  user.public_profile.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender
  user.token = auth.credentials.token
  user.expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  user.save!
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. I had to change one thing in the code that you passed. I changed the line user.public_profile.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender by user.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender Thank you so much.

Comment: you could help me with something else ? I wonder how to get a list of friends. I still can not find this information . Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: You app must have the user_friends permission from BOTH the user and his/her friend in order to see the relationship.  So, it is possible to get a list of friends from the API but it will ONLY include friends that are also using your app and have also granted you the appropriate permissions.